# Oracle 11g - Passing boolean to stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to create a stored procedure with boolean input parameter:-

**Step 1:** I have created a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE STOREBOOL ( BOOLVAL NUMBER(1));
```

**Step 2:** I created a stored procedure

Based on the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/tips3.htm#1005343 created a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE boolProc(x boolean)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO storebool("boolval") VALUES(x);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Output is:-

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

Similarly created a second procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE boolWrap(x int)
AS
BEGIN
IF (x=1) THEN
boolProc(TRUE);
ELSE
boolProc(FALSE);
END IF;
END;
```

Output is:-

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

**Step 3:** Executing the code

```
BEGIN
boolWrap(1);
END;
/
```

It is showing the following error:

```
boolWrap(1);
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1
PLS-00905: object SCOTT.BOO
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

How do i run it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice the "created with compilation errors" messages? You can see what the errors were immediately after you see that with `show errors`, or by querying the `user_errors` view.

In the first procedure you're dong this:

```
INSERT INTO storebool("boolval") VALUES(x);
```

... which has two problems: (a) you don't have a column called `"boolval"`; it was created unquoted as `BOOLVAL` so either refer to it unquoted, or quoted but in uppercase as it appears in the data dictionary; and (b) you're trying to set a `number` column to a `boolean` value. Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type, but there is no implicit conversion available. You need to define what number represents TRUE, and what represents FALSE, and then insert that number instead of the boolean `x` argument. So you'd see errors like:

```
4/46           PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
4/28           PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "boolval": invalid identifier
```

The `boolWrap` can't compile because `boolProc` isn't valid.

Your `boolProc` and `boolWrap` procedures are reversed really; you want the 'real' procedure to take a number argument, and the wrapper to take a boolean and convert that to a number to call the `real` one.

This might make more sense:

```
CREATE TABLE STOREBOOL (BOOLVAL NUMBER(1),
  CONSTRAINT BOOLCHECK CHECK (BOOLVAL IN (0,1))
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE boolProc(p_bool_num number)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO storebool(boolval) VALUES (p_bool_num);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE boolWrap(p_bool boolean)
AS
    l_bool_num number;
BEGIN
    IF p_bool THEN
        boolProc(1);
    ELSE
        boolProc(0);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Then you can call `boolProc` with a number argument, or `boolWrap` with a boolean argument:

```
BEGIN
    boolProc(1);
END;
/

BEGIN
    boolWrap(false);
END;
/

select * from storebool;

   BOOLVAL
----------
         1 
         0
```

Comment: When calling it from Java Code. I did the following:- Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@<hoststring>", "scott", "tiger"); CallableStatement pstmt = conn.prepareCall("begin boolWrap(?); end;"); pstmt.setBoolean(1, true); pstmt.execute(); But it shows the  error 6550ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BOOLWRAP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @sasi - [from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#setBoolean_java_lang_String__boolean_), it's converted to a `BIT` type. [See this too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28981): "The JDBC drivers do not support the passing of BOOLEAN parameters to PL/SQL stored procedures". You'd need to call `boolProc` instead, with `setInt`. But... I guess from the names that this is where you started?

Comment: My requirement is to pass the boolean value from java. So i am using boolWrap. Is there a way to pass boolean from java.

Comment: Not with `setBoolean`, but you can just decode it in the `setInt` call for `boolProc`; e.g. `setInt(1, boolvar ? 1 : 0)`?

Comment: But having separate `boolProc` and `boolWrap` in the doc you linked to is for accessing an existing proc that expects a boolean really; if all you are doing is inserting a number into a table then a boolean wrapper around that is pointless unless you want to call that from PL/SQL. If you have to pass a number (via JDBC) then you don't need the wrapper proc at all?